# Unit testing typescript classes with jest ("Cannot read property '__extends' of null")

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, typescript, jestjs

I am trying to test class "a" (which inherits from class "b") with jest. The typescript compiler prepends the file compiled javascript of "a" with

```
var __extends = this.__extends || function (d, b) { ... };
```

unfortunately `this` is null, when running the unit test, so I am getting

```
Cannot read property '__extends' of null
```

I am using jest-cli@0.2.1 to run the tests and typescript@1.4.1 to compile my typescript files.
Normally `this` would point to window, when the files are run in a browser.

Does someone know how to get around that issue?

Answer (score 1):

This error is not that `__extends` is `null`, it describes one of two scenarios.

Either you have forgotten to include the file that contains the base class, or you have included it after the file that contains the sub class.

Practical example:

```
<!-- Base class first -->
<script src="b.js"></script>
<!-- Now the sub class -->
<script src="a.js"></script>
<!-- Now things that depend on the sub class -->
<script src="tests.js"></script>
```

If you did this in any other order, you'd get a problem.

If you are compiling to a single file, you'll need to make sure your reference comments are in order to ensure the classes appear in the correct order in the combined file.

Comment: I think the issue is actually that jest is calling the test function using `apply(null, args)`. The error message indicates that `this` is null (why jest would do that, I have no idea... `{}` seems like a better choice)

Answer (score 0):

This error is the most common error I see when require.js isn't set up properly. Was requirejs properly loaded/configured?

Nathan

Comment: this is an issue with jest ... jest is setting up it's own require function

Comment: Sorry, wasn't careful enough in my reading... thought I could help.